# How can I move my fridge in and out faster for repairs?

Tags: refrigerator

We have an older 48 inch wide subzero that has been undergoing repairs for the last month. Everytime the tech needs to bring the fridge in and out of its position it's a complete pain in the behind to put the fridge back into the proper position it originally was in.

What can i put under the fridge "foot" to make the glid back and forth much easier and faster?

Comment: I slide an upside-down bathroom rug under mine to scoot it around. The rubber backing sticks to the fridge bottom, while the rug's carpet's yarn slides across my floor w/o scratching.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Provided you have enough vertical clearance, these sort of "appliance sliders" can be effective:

[image]

Then what about something like this if you don't have clearance:

[image]

Called "Appliance sliders".

Comment: I don't have enough vertical clearance.

Comment: Does you Sub-Zero have the condenser cooling out the front or bottom front? If you don't' have clearance for these, make sure you have required ventilation clearances for your fridge. If it has any ventilating out the back, that could be part of your fridge's problems. If the heat can't get out, it can't cool the inside properly.